# edits are not getting saved in livetable edit plugin

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery, jeditable

I am using "live-table edit" plugin from http://preview.jqueryajaxphp.com/livetableedit/ .Everything works perfectly ,However none of my edits are getting saved! What could be causing that? Everything looks fine. When I edit a cell, the briefly "flashes" pale yellow,it shows updated value in cell. But when I submit data updated field still will be having old value.When I checked html source(view-source) showing old value(AAA).

[image]

[image: enter code here]

```
    <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="assets/css/custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="assets/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/bootstrap-editable.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="media/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="extensions/TableTools/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="extensions/TableTools/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
    <link href="media/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet"   type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css"> 
    <script src="extensions/Plugins/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

jQuery(document).ready(function() {  
        $.fn.editable.defaults.mode = 'popup';
        $('.xedit').editable();     
        $(document).on('click','.editable-submit',function(){
             $(this).closest('td').children('span').attr('id');
             $('.input-sm').val();
             $(this).closest('td').children('span');
        });
});
```

Please help me.

Comment: Did you try to see console logs of, for example, firebug? Since data submited by some requests, you can easily see what response do you get after submission. This response may contain errors which will help you

Comment: @lolbas , thanks for helping me , i am getting  this  "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'row' of query.dataTables.js:8581 undefined " in colsole.

Comment: Is there any solution to this problem... I had even tried xeditable (without ajax call )but there also somehow after submitting complete table to servlet data is getting vanished...